# Java scanner class storing multiple int values from datafile into an array

Tags: java, arrays, java.util.scanner, data-files

I am trying to create the below method to read the "studentmarks.txt" file. However, I cannot get students marks to be read as an int such as 65 60 52 and stored into an Array. It keeps outputing the error "java.util.InputMismatchException null". How would I go about fixing this without altering the format of the "studentmarks.txt" file? Thank you!

```
public void readMarksData(String fileName) throws FileNotFoundException
{


    File dataFile = new File(fileName);
    Scanner scanner = new Scanner(dataFile);

    String nameOfCohort = scanner.nextLine(); //1
    System.out.println(nameOfCohort);

    int noOfMarks = scanner.nextInt();  //2
    System.out.println(noOfMarks);

    scanner.nextLine();
    while( scanner.hasNext() )
    {

       scanner.useDelimiter("[,\n]");
       String name = scanner.next();      //3
       System.out.println(name);



         //            int marks[] = new int[3];
         //            for(int i = 0 ; i <= 3 ; i++)
         //            {
         //               marks[i] = scanner.nextInt();
         //            }

       int marks[] = new int[100];

       int markOne = scanner.nextInt();  //4 java.util.InputMismatchException null
       marks = new int[markOne];
       System.out.println(markOne);
       scanner.nextLine();



       int markTwo = scanner.nextInt();      //5
       marks = new int[markTwo];
       scanner.nextLine();

       int markThree = scanner.nextInt();      //6
       marks = new int[markThree];
       scanner.nextLine();
       //              
       //System.out.println(markOne + " " + markTwo + " " + markThree);

    }
    scanner.close();
}
```

studentmarks.txt:

```
CS1 Group 2
3
Andreas Antoniades
65 85 77
Charlotte Brocklebank
87 93 81
suzanne dawson
0 55 42
```

StudentRecord Class:

```
public class StudentRecord
{

   private String name;
   private String noOfMarks; 
   private int[] marks;

   public StudentRecord(String name)
   {
     marks = new int[24];
     this.name = name;  
   }
```

Comment: You should explain the problem before showing the code such that it is easier for someone to understand what is your requirement and then what is your problem.

Answer (score 1):

```
int result = Integer.parseInt(number);
```

You can use the `parseInt(String val)` method to parse a string value of 65 to an integer value and the store that in an array